# fb ios sdk 4.5 crashes in iOS7

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

any one come across this problem,

while creating FBSDKGameRequestContent , with fb sdk 4.5 ios, its getting crashed in ios7.

attached crash logs here:

> Thread : Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException 0  CoreFoundation
>   0x30956f83 **exceptionPreprocess + 130 1  libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x3b0a3ccf objc_exception_throw + 38 2  CoreFoundation
>
>   0x3095a917 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 202 3 
>   CoreFoundation                 0x30959203 ___forwarding_** + 706 4 
>   CoreFoundation                 0x308a8768 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24 5
>                     0x0037a329
>   -[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection _validateFieldsParamForGetRequests:] (FBSDKGraphRequestConnection.m:346) 6  
>   0x0037a61d -[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection requestWithBatch:timeout:]
>   (FBSDKGraphRequestConnection.m:378) 7  
>   0x00379443 -[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection start]
>   (FBSDKGraphRequestConnection.m:175) 8  
>   0x003593e3 -[FBSDKGraphRequest startWithCompletionHandler:]
>   (FBSDKGraphRequest.m:180) 9                     0x001fbef7
>   -[FBSDKGameRequestFrictionlessRecipientCache _updateCache] (FBSDKGameRequestFrictionlessRecipientCache.m:91) 10 
>   0x001fbb71 -[FBSDKGameRequestFrictionlessRecipientCache init]
>   (FBSDKGameRequestFrictionlessRecipientCache.m:39) 11 
>   0x001e726d +[FBSDKGameRequestDialog initialize]
>   (FBSDKGameRequestDialog.m:45) 12 libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x3b0a453d _class_initialize + 572 13 libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x3b0a89e3 lookUpImpOrForward + 130 14 libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x3b0a8957 _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache3 + 34 15 libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x3b0ad8b9 _objc_msgSend_uncached + 24 16 
>   0x00143285 -[JLFriendsViewController createFacebookGameRequest]
>   (JLFriendsViewController.m:1095) 17 
>   0x00081457 -[JLFBFriendsTableviewDelegate
>   tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]
>   (JLFBFriendsTableviewDelegate.m:147) 18 UIKit
>   0x3329203f -[UITableView
>   _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1078 19 UIKit                          0x33344357 -[UITableView
>   _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 214 20 UIKit                          0x331f36d5 _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 316 21 UIKit
>   0x3316c53b _afterCACommitHandler + 430 22 CoreFoundation
>   0x30922255
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 20 23 CoreFoundation                 0x3091fbf9 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 284
>   24 CoreFoundation                 0x3091ff3b __CFRunLoopRun + 730 25
>   CoreFoundation                 0x3088aebf CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
>   26 CoreFoundation                 0x3088aca3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
>   27 GraphicsServices               0x357ad663 GSEventRunModal + 138 28
>   UIKit                          0x331d714d UIApplicationMain + 1136 29
>                      0x0011d39b main (main.m:16)

Comment: Can you check any callback that you have set on the SDK calls are correct?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this crash too and wasn't able to reproduce it locally but it seems that the problem is `FBSDKGraphRequestConnection.m` using `containsString:` on `NSString`, which is only available on iOS 8.0+.

```
// in NSString.h (iOS 8.4)
- (BOOL)containsString:(NSString *)aString NS_AVAILABLE(10_10, 8_0);
```

The corresponding line in FB SDK 4.5 is

```
// in FBSDKGraphRequestConnection.m (line 349)
![request.graphPath containsString:@"fields="]) {
```

However, this issue seems to be fixed in 4.5.1 (see [this diff](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/commit/3e25e34579917558967ac180509e5f3e72c8d82f)).

The line under consideration is now

```
// in FBSDKGraphRequestConnection.m (line 349)
[request.graphPath rangeOfString:@"fields="].location == NSNotFound) {
```

So update to 4.5.1 and you should be fine.